# Jquery hide parent div on click of li class if another li has specific class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a parent DIV which has UL and LI. Only first LI has some specific class(say 
    .closeSuperDept
). I need to hide the entire DIV(#departmentMenu) if the first LI has class(closeSuperDept) on click of rest of LI's(which has the class "dropdown-toggle").

```
<div id="#departmentMenu">
<ul>
<li class="closeSuperDept">Heading</li>
<li class="dropdown-toggle">item1</li>
<li class="dropdown-toggle">item1</li>
<li class="dropdown-toggle">item1</li>
</ul>
</div>


$(document).on('click', '#departmentMenu .dropdown-toggle', function(){ 
var $breadcrumb = $("#departmentMenu .dropdown-toggle");
if ($breadcrumb.hasClass('closeSuperDept')){
$('#departmentMenu').hide();
}
});
```

I tried above code, I  am not able to  get the expected output.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
$(document).on('click', '#departmentMenu .dropdown-toggle', function () {
    var $breadcrumb = $("#departmentMenu li:first"); 
    if ($breadcrumb.hasClass('closeSuperDept')) {
        $('#departmentMenu').hide();
    }
});
```

- `var $breadcrumb = $("#departmentMenu li:first");` will get the first `li`  element inside the parent `departmentMenu`

Comment: @palash : Forget to mention! The first LI will be present in DOM always, only thing is the css class will change from 'display:none' to 'display:block'. i have added the following code and it worked fine.                                                                                                                                                                                                                      if($('.closeSuperDept').css('display') == 'block')
        {
            $('#departmentMenu').hide();
        }

Comment: @Ramesh: yes, you can do that to check if its hidden or not.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<div id="#departmentMenu">
<ul>
<li class="closeSuperDept">Heading</li>
<li class="dropdown-toggle">item1</li>
<li class="dropdown-toggle">item1</li>
<li class="dropdown-toggle">item1</li>
</ul>
</div>


var $menu = $('#departmentMenu').on('click', '.dropdown-toggle', function(){ 
    if ($menu.find('li.closeSuperDept:first-child').length){
        $menu.hide();
    }
});
```

What it does is the following:
if you click on a '.dropdown-toggle' inside the '#departmentMenu' the script searches for a 'li' with '.closeSuperDept' inside the menu which is the first child inside its parent. if it finds it, the menu will be hidden